# Javascript not showing value of list item

Tags: jquery, html

```
<ul class="myul">
    <li value="2" data-liname="2">2</li>
    <li value="3" data-liname="3">3</li>
    <li value="3+" data-liname="3+">3+</li>
</ul>
```

With jQuery :

```
$(".myul li").on("click", function(){
    var myval = $(this).data("liname");
    var myval1 = $(this).val();
});
```

When I select `3+` I can get the value of `myval` but with `myval1` it shows only 3 and not 3+. `myval1` works fine for other values. Only when a nimber has the `+` sign it chooses to ignore it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `li` values attributes, they specify a number value for ordering in an ordered list. Only number parts are taken from the values, thus making your `3+` become a `3`. Here's a snippet demonstrating what happens:

```html
<ol class="myul">
    <li value="2" data-liname="2">2nd</li>
    <li data-liname="2">3rd</li>
    <li data-liname="2">4th</li>
    <li data-liname="2">5th</li>
  
    <li value="100+@#$**$&">100th, notice string part is removed</li>
    <li>101th</li>

    <li value="105+">105th, notice + is removed</li>
</ol>
```

Notice that this is an `ol`, or ordered list. What the value attribute does is set the number of ordering. In the above snippet you can see that the non-number parts are removed from `value`, leaving only number parts for ordering.

---

What this all means is that when you call `$(this).val()`, it returns the `value` attribute. But since the value attribute gets rid of *all parts after the first non-numeric character* because they are not used in ordering ordered lists, it gives you 3, instead of 3+.

Comment: So am i ok to use the `data-liname` attribute? Is this accepted?

Comment: @Somename Sure, this is fine. It accepts a string and is good for passing data. :)

Comment: @AndrewL. can an anchor tag have value attribute?I tried to access it using an older version of jQuery but it did not work.

Comment: @techie_28 The anchor tag doesn't have a value attribute.

Comment: @AndrewL.yes it doesnt but would `.val()` work if I assign `value=something` on an anchor tag?

Comment: @techie_28 No. Since they have no value tag, jQuery doesn't get anything. [Here's a test](https://jsfiddle.net/2jhr7syx/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. This works.

```
$(".myul li").on("click", function(){
  var myval = $(this).data("liname");
  var myval1 =$(this).attr('value');
});
```